# Solve integer expression expected error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

writing this code give me an integer expression expected on IF line
how can i solve this?!

```
uservalue=$1

df -h | tail -n +2 > dfout.txt

cat dfout.txt | while read Filesystem Size Used Avail Use Mounted

do 

use_perc="{Use%?}"

if [ "use_perc" -gt "$uservalue"]

then

echo "$Filesystem is full"

else

echo "$Filesystem is not full"

fi

done
```

Comment: `$use_perc`: don't forget the dollar sign.

Comment: And add a space before `]` in the same line.

Comment: You also need a `$` in this line: `use_perc="${Use%?}"`

Comment: You could also use: `while read ... done < <(df -h | tail -n +2)` and avoid the temporary file.

Comment: "how can i solve this?" - the same way you would solve *anything else*. check what you're doing: `echo [ "use_perc" -gt "$uservalue"]`

Comment: sign added, temporary file solved, the same error appear